# OData stop expanding when return a List instead of IEnumerable

Tags: c#, entity-framework, azure-sql-database, odata, expand

I always returned an IEnumerable object on the OData controller. But since the tables starts to be big enough to fill up the buffer, I started returning a List, like it is here:

```cs
        [HttpGet("table1")]
        [EnableQuery()]
        public async Task<List<Table1>> GetAllTable1()
        {
            var values = await _mediator.Send(new Table1GetAllODataRequest { });
            return values.ToList();
        }
```

After starting to return a List, the tables do not fill up the buffer anymore, but the $expand is not working, it always returns with null, like this:

```json
    {
        "equipment": null,
        "equipmentId": 452,
        "id": 1
    }
```

And the expected was:

```json
{
        "equipment": {
            "code": "ABC",
            "description": "ABCD1",            
            "enabled": false,
            "id": 452
        },
        "equipmentId": 452,
        "id": 1
    }
```

It seems like when I do the "ToList" it loses the references of the Equipment table.

The request I am doing is the following:

```
https://localhost:44382/api/odata/table1?$expand=equipment
```

Is there someone who knows what to do in this situation? I can't go back to return the IEnumerable because it is filling up the buffer with too much data.

Comment: You have to use the code that return data.   Why are you getting back a lot of data?  Maybe you need to filter the data to return less data.

Comment: If buffering is a problem then add a filter expression to the query or your implementation might be plain wrong, in OData `.ToList()` is probably the most destructive form of evil you can just throw in there to _see if it works_.  We need to know what the implementation of `_mediator` is to provide a useful response.

Answer (score 1):

It's not that intuitive what your Mediator implementation is returning, but my guess is that in one case the data serialized in the request was lazy loading the related data (which would be quite slow especially when dealing with collections of results) or somehow eager loading it, where in the current case it is not. You can have your mediator eager load the related data, but you'd almost certainly hit your "buffer" barrier. (I'm guessing response size)

Ultimately when working with data over HTTP you will hit a barrier where the requested data is simply too big to possibly send, or it is impractical to send to the client. There are a few things you need to consider moving forward:

1. Pagination: This is enabling your view to load pages of data, say 50-100 rows at a time, and presenting the user to either select pages, or employ a dynamic scrolling system to load additional data in pieces. This allows you to load a level of detail you need regardless of how big the data source gets without ever hitting memory or request size boundaries.
2. Projection: This is changing what your view is bound to from raw entity graphs down to a View Model or DTO that contains just the fields from the table(s) that the view actually needs. This is done in EF using `Select()` or via Automapper's `ProjectTo()` methods. Rarely do you need every column from each related table, so projection can reduce the memory/transmission of each row the view needs to display quite considerably.
3. Asynchronous Expansion: When presenting a view that benefits from being able to "drill down" and show increasing amounts of detail on demand, you have the choice of passing everything at once when the view loads, or passing the basic information and requesting additional detail if and when it is actually needed. A classic example is where you might use tabs or expandable regions for related information. You can load and pass all of this information when you load the page, even though 80% of the time no one even uses it, or you can summarize the main view to what is visible on the screen and make a fast Ajax request to fetch detail when a user expands to actually want to view the detail. A classic example is search results for a table. These typically display a single line of fields, so project these summaries and the related ID(s) to a summary view model, then when the user wants to select one to get the details, perform an Ajax call or navigate to a detail view to fetch the detail by ID.